# Keeping the subprocess environment for the caller process in C#

Tags: c#, process, environment-variables

I'd like to set up a Visual C++ toolchain to be used inside my C# application. For the toolchain it's recommended to call `vcvarsall` (or some subvariant). My problem is that the calling process - my application - will not get to keep the environment set up by `vcvarsall`. Can this somehow be achieved?

```cs
// First set up the toolchain with vcvarsall
var vcvarsallProc = new Process 
{ 
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = vcvarsallPath,
        Arguments = "x86",
        UseShellExecute = false,
    }
};
vcvarsallProc.Start();
vcvarsallProc.WaitForExit();

// Invoke the linker for example
var linkerProc = new Process 
{ 
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "LINK.exe",
        Arguments = " foo.obj /OUT:a.exe",
        UseShellExecute = false,
    }
};
linkerProc.Start();
linkerProc.WaitForExit();
// ERROR: 'LINK' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, this is pretty much impossible without a hassle.

The best one can do is chain multiple commands, which will run in the same environment. It can be done like so:

```cs
var linkerProc = new Process 
{ 
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "cmd.exe",
        Arguments = $"/C ({vcvarsallPath} {vcvarsallArgs}) && (LINK.exe {linkArgs})",
        UseShellExecute = false,
    }
};
```

Hiding this behind a function like `InvokeWithEnvironment`, and it's pretty painless to use.